# What is the yellow compound formed in electrolysis of brine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

Last week, I tried to conduct electrolysis of brine in my house using copper electrodes and 6V battery. After sometime, the entire solution turned orange/yellow. The yellow substance formed a kind of cloud at first and later it turned to an orange colloid. Does anyone know what the yellow coloured substance might be?

Comment: Given distilled water was used, it's probably copper(I) hydroxide from the electrode. Try to heat it up and see what happens. Yellow-orange $\ce{CuOH}$ should decompose to dark-red $\ce{Cu2O}.$

Comment: I think you're right because what I had noticed is that the cathode was getting shorter and used up. Anode was unaffected.

Comment: Could be as a result of Na metal in the cathode and the anode is the one used up.